# Как работать с большими файлами

Tags: c, c++

Для работы с файлами я использую функции C: fopen, fread, fwrite, fseek, ftell, fclose. fseek и ftell работают с 32-битными числами, но если файл будет больше 2 ГБ, то будут проблемы. В Visual C++ есть функции _ftelli64 и _fseeki64, но похоже, что это расширение Microsoft. Есть ли какой-то кросскомпиляторный аналог этих функций?

Comment: fseeko, ftello?

Comment: Таких у меня нету.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *LSEEK64(3)*                 Linux Programmer's Manual                *LSEEK64(3)*
>
> **NAME**
>
> *lseek64* - reposition 64-bit read/write file offset
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>   #define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
>   #include <sys/types.h>
>   #include <unistd.h>
>
>   off64_t lseek64(int fd, off64_t offset, int whence);
> ```

**UPDATE**

Из `stdio.h`:

```
#ifdef __USE_LARGEFILE64
extern FILE *fopen64 (__const char *__restrict __filename,
              __const char *__restrict __modes) __wur;
extern FILE *freopen64 (__const char *__restrict __filename,
            __const char *__restrict __modes,
            FILE *__restrict __stream) __wur;
#endif

...

#ifdef __USE_LARGEFILE64
extern int fseeko64 (FILE *__stream, __off64_t __off, int __whence);
extern __off64_t ftello64 (FILE *__stream) __wur;
extern int fgetpos64 (FILE *__restrict __stream, fpos64_t *__restrict __pos);
extern int fsetpos64 (FILE *__stream, __const fpos64_t *__pos);
#endif
```

**UPDATE 2**

Из `MinGW/include/stdio.h` «gcc в 32-бит винде»:

```
#if __MSVCRT_VERSION__ >= 0x800
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _fseek_nolock (FILE*, long, int);
_CRTIMP long __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    _ftell_nolock (FILE*);

_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _fseeki64 (FILE*, __int64, int);
_CRTIMP __int64 __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _ftelli64 (FILE*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _fseeki64_nolock (FILE*, __int64, int);
_CRTIMP __int64 __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _ftelli64_nolock (FILE*);
#endif
```

Попробуйте, может подойдет. Сразу говорю, сам не пробовал и даже не искал инфу по ним.

Если заработает, то для переносимости оберните в `#ifedf`-ах в POSIX-овые `fseeko()` и `ftello()`.

Comment: Ну вопрос-то было про sream ввод/вывод

Comment: Пардон, обновил для stream

Comment: У меня нет такого. Подключал stdio.h, но функций для 64 нет. Пробовал даже определять макрос __USE_LARGEFILE64 перед включением, но не помогло. Даже поиском в stdio.h не смог найти. Это из какого компилятора? Может быть, это тоже расширение какого-то компилятора?

Comment: Linux avp-xub11 3.0.0-16-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 17:50:54 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


gcc.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

@GLmonster, у Вас видимо изделие Б. Гейтса. Сочувствую...

Comment: @GLmonster posix'ом определяются функции fseeko, ftello. Но если комплект от ms, то о posix говорить несколько неприлично.

Comment: >у Вас видимо изделие Б. Гейтса. Сочувствую...

>posix'ом определяются функции fseeko, ftello. Но если комплект от ms, то о posix говорить несколько неприлично.

 То есть этот способ мне не подходит - он не *кросскомпиляторный*.

Comment: Если Вы в своей программе сделаете под #ifdef-ом макросы ftello и fseecko, то получится *кросскомпиляторный* код.

Comment: @GLmonster Он не кроссплатформенный. Так же как и пресловутый fork (или select, который и для сокетов, и для файлов)

Comment: С select (о fork даже говорить не стоит) соглашусь, с 64-бит seek нет. Если ОС (реализация stdio) поддерживает длинный seek для FILE \*, то неважно, как он называется.

Comment: Заменил ftell и fseek на fgetpos и fsetpos, которые принимают указатель на позицию в файле. Пока не очень понял, чем они отличаются, но у меня всё работает правильно. Скорее всего, они отличаются в текстовом и бинарном файлах, но я пока использую только бинарный.

Answer (score 1):

Ниженаписанное следует считать комментарием к дискуссии в ответе [@avp](/users/232/avp), просто я опять не уложился в ограничения комментария ;)

[@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster), функции fgetpos и fsetpos работают с структурой fpos_t, к сожалению, стандарт очень расплывчато определяет этот тип:

> fpos_t is a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

Из этой формулировки непонятно - в любом ли файле, в любой ли системе.

Провел небольшое исследование (openSUSE Linux, 32-bit):

```
// stdio.h
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
typedef _G_fpos_t fpos_t;
#else
typedef _G_fpos64_t fpos_t;
#endif

// _G_config.h
typedef struct
{
  __off_t __pos;
  __mbstate_t __state;
} _G_fpos_t;
typedef struct
{
  __off64_t __pos;
  __mbstate_t __state;
} _G_fpos64_t;
```

У меня константа `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` не определена. Таким образом, выбор типа для представления смещения в файле определяется компилятором, что не делает и этот подход кроссплатформенным.

Однако, если ориентироваться только на 64-битные платформы, подход с использованием fgetpos/fsetpos мне представляется более переносимым, чем fseek/ftell. Интерфейс функций fseek/ftell использует long int для представления смещения, а если верить [таблице моделей данных](http://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0012/), long int может быть 32-битным на 64-битной платформе. В то же время fgetpos/fsetpos опираются на memsize-тип off_t. О том же говорит [статья Data Size Neutrality and 64-bit Support](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html) на unix.org. См. раздел Porting issues:

> Use utilities such as grep to locate and check all instances of the following:
> ...
> - The functions `lseek()` , `fseek()` , `ftell()` , `fgetpos()` , and so on. Use either `off_t` or `fpos_t` as appropriate for offset arguments. Do not use `int` or `long` to store file offsets.

Вообще, спасибо за вопрос, интересная пища для размышлений и обсуждения со студентами ;)

Comment: У меня fpos_t определён по другому:

    #if     defined (_POSIX_)
    typedef long fpos_t;
    #define _FPOSOFF(fp) ((long)(fp))
    #else   /* _POSIX_ */

    #if     !__STDC__
    /* At this point we could switch both to long long, but we won't do that till next version to avoid any potential compat issues */
    typedef __int64 fpos_t;
    #define _FPOSOFF(fp) ((long)(fp))
    #else
    typedef long long fpos_t;
    #define _FPOSOFF(fp) ((long)(fp))
    #endif
    #endif  /* _POSIX_ */

#define _FPOS_T_DEFINED
#endif

Comment: >функции fgetpos и fsetpos работают с структурой fpos_t, к сожалению, стандарт очень расплывчато определяет этот тип

 Ну и ладно. Вопрос уже не так стал актуален, потому что я планирую переписывать свой проект на D. Там сделано всё намного продуманнее, чем в C++.

Comment: @GLmonster, у Вас же все нормально. Не заморачивайтесь абсолютной переносимостью своих программ. 

В реальной жизни программа, которой может потребоваться некоторая доводка для существующей инфраструктуры у конкретного заказчика, оказывается в выигрыше. (И лично автор (команда) тоже)

Answer (score 0):

На мой вгляд, Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону "Проецируемыемых в память файлов". 
 Более подробно можете почитать в книге "Джеффри Рихтер, Кристоф Назар - Windows via C/C++. Программирование на языке Visual C++" Глава 17. Проецируемые в память файлы

Comment: Я сам знаю, как работать с большими файлами средствами Windows (функция SetFilePointerEx). Я так и делал, но потом решил переделать на функции из стандартной библиотеки, чтобы код стал кроссплатформенным.

Comment: Не могу сказать точно, насколько возможна в данном случае кросслатформенность и будет ли это работать быстро, тем более ограничение-то на уровне операционной системы. Тем более, если захотите писать 64-битный код, то он будет работать по разному на разных машинах. Здесь все упирается в возможности операционной системы, а не возможности языка программирования

Comment: При чём здесь ОС? Большие файлы могут быть в абсолютно любой ОС. Любая ОС должна уметь работать с файлами > 2 ГБ.

>Тем более, если захотите писать 64-битный код, то он будет работать по разному на разных машинах.

 В смысле, по-разному? И при чём здесь 64-битный код? Работать с большими файлами нужно и в 32-битном.

Comment: Работать с большими файлами нужно и в 32-битном.

Windows 95?

Comment: > Любая ОС должна уметь работать с файлами > 2 ГБ.
Вы же сами написали "но если файл будет больше 2 ГБ, то будут проблемы"

Comment: >Вы же сами написали "но если файл будет больше 2 ГБ, то будут проблемы"

 Проблемы будут, потому что я не смогу передавать функции fseek и получать от ftell значения больше INT_MAX. Я ищу им **кроссплатформенную** и **кросскомпиляторную** замену. Проецирование в память мне не нужно. Мне нужна возможность работать с указателем любого файла.

>Windows 95?

 Не понял, при чём тут Windows 95?

 Я вас не понимаю. Пишите прямо, без намёков.

Comment: FAT12 -- файловая система? А как там с файлами >2ГБ?

Comment: >FAT12 -- файловая система? А как там с файлами >2ГБ?

 FAT12? Не знаю такой. Опечатка? Знаю FAT32, но там ограничение до 4 ГБ. Я имел в виду, почему нельзя было сделать аналог функций, принимающих или возвращающих 64 бита в библиотеке C? Если даже ОС не поддерживает большие файлы, функция записи могла бы работать, пока не будет превышен максимальный размер, а потом вернуть ошибку. Остальные функции не превысят этого размер, и ошибок вообще быть не должно.

Comment: Сейчас только понял, что мы говорим о разных вещах. В общем, можно работать с большими файлами двумя способами:
1) проецируя в память файлы. Данный подход не может быть кроссплатформенным.
2) поблочное чтение файла (т.е. мы не выгружаем файлы в память, а постепенно обходим весь файл со смещением)

Comment: @GLMonster Смотрите статью FAT в википедии. Разумеется, никаких файлов >2Гб в FAT12 или FAT16 быть не может. @theathlet почему подход (1) не может быть кроссплатформенным?